# Как изменить цвет текста по умолчанию в TextView, генерируемых динамически в FlexboxLayout с помощью темы или стиля?

Tags: android, textview

Как изменить цвет текста по умолчанию в TextView, генерируемых динамически в FlexboxLayout с помощью темы или стиля?

Comment: почему нельзя указывать цвет при генерации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам надо

1. Создать стиль для `TextView`:

   ```
   <style name="MyTextViewStyle">
       <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. Создать стиль, содержащий вышеуказанный стиль:

   ```
   <style name="MyTheme">
       <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/MyTextViewStyle</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. В разметке указать стиль из п.2 через аттрибут `android:theme="@style/MyTheme"` для вьюхи, внутри которой вам надо менять стиль для текстовых полей, т.е. припишите это у FlexboxLayout